# How to get the details from an HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a html stored in a variable and I want to get the details from html using JavaScript. How can I do it?

following is my html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>1. Heat the butter<br/>2. Add the onions<br/></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If by details you mean its content, then `htmlElement.textContent`. If not then please clarify what you mean by details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DOM element and set it's `innerHTML` to the HTML string you have, then you can parse it's HTML component.

```js
var _html = '<html><body><p>1. Heat the butter<br/>2. Add the onions<br/></p></body></html>';
var el = document.createElement('html');
el.innerHTML = _html;

var _el = el.getElementsByTagName('p');
alert(_el[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear .
Id you attach the string containing this piece of html , you can get info by using simple dom api features such (`querySelector` etc.)

if it is just a string you should have to extraxct what you want from string by using javascript string methods or regex.

You can find regex tutorial [here](http://www.regexr.com/) and for queryselector check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and javascript string methods can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)
if you clarify your question i can help further